# TypeError: val.toString is not a function - mysql npm

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm, package

I use the package 'mysql' with NPM on a nodeJS backend and I don't understand the error message :

TypeError: val.toString is not a function
at Object.escape (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:52:33)
at Object.objectToValues (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:180:89)
at Object.escape (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:54:26)
at Object.format (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:100:19)
at Connection.format (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:271:20)
at Connection.query (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:189:22)
at Function.create (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/models/message.js:7:19)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/server.js:41:17
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodeJS_livredor/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)

My code :

```js
let mysql = require('mysql');

let connexion = mysql.createConnection({
    host        : 'localhost',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : 'root',
    database    : 'livredor'
});

console.log('avant connexion.connect');
connexion.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(`Erreur de connexion: ${err.stack}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`Connecté`);
});

module.exports = connexion;
```

I see both console.log in my console, so I guess it's come from 'connexion.connect' but I don't know why.

If someone can help, ty :)

Comment: This seems like something is wrong with your ```mysql``` dependencies... Have you tried deleting ```node_modules``` and reinstalling your modules? Also, what version of node and npm do you use?

Comment: Hey, yes I del all the modules and reinstall, nothing change, same error. I use node 14.4.0 et npm 6.14.5.

Comment: On second thought, this looks like a problem with one of your express routes. Does the error occur on a request to one of your routes? If so, could you show us the code for that route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a moron,

Ty !! that was that the request was incorrect.

my route before :

```js
        const   Message = require('./models/message');

        Message.create(req, () => {
            req.flash('succes', "Votre message a bien été posté.");
            
        })
```

my route now :

```js
        const   Message = require('./models/message');

        Message.create(req.body.message, () => {
            req.flash('succes', "Votre message a bien été posté.");
            
        })
```

Thanks again :)